# Bizarre Disk Use Problem

Tags: kde, open-files

I have an external hard drive on which I use `rsync` to backup my home directory. Today, I tried to `umount` the drive. It said it was busy. So, I used `fuser` to figure out who was using it:

```
/media/Panp9 Backups: 

10198rce 10283rce 10284rce 10337rce 10338rce 10339rce 10341rce
10345rce 10348rce 10353rce 10354rce 10356rce 10362rce 10367rce
10371rce 10374rce 10378rce 10384rce 10387rce 10389rce 10396rce
10433rce 10436rce 10439rce 10441rce 10443rce 10447rce 10448rce
10457rce 10460rce 10466rce 10467rce 10473rce 10478rce 10487rce
10492rce 10504rce 10522rce 10538rce 10555rce 10560rce 10561rce
10562rce 10563rce 10564rce 10565rce 10566rce 10567rce 10720rce
10721rce 10722rce 10723rce 11083rce 11088rce 11090e 11094e
```

Most of these seem to be various bids of Nepomuk. So, I went ahead and issued a `fuser -c -k` in my frustration. Apparently, this command (without `sudo`, I should mention) managed to kill X11. I'm at a loss and can't figure out why this is happening. Can anyone help me?

**System Details:**

- Intel i7, 4 cores
- 8 GB RAM
- Linux Mint Nadia 14 KDE

Comment: not familiar with the NEPOMUK framework, other than a couple of articles I read in the past and accepting the risk of being obvious, did you try disabling it and checking if the problem stops. It might be some other thing triggering the NEPOMUK behavior. Just a thought...

Comment: @Mel_Burslan: I did, and none of those processes quit. In the end, I solved this by unplugging the disk (the data is all stored somewhere else too), and I;m going to use a different backup solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Most of these seem to be various bids of Nepomuk.” But you killed *all* of them, not just the Nepomuk ones. So some other process must have been caught in the fray — presumably one critical to KDE, without which the window manager or the session manager crashed, possibly the window manager or the session manager itself.

If you haven't logged back in, check the file `~/.xsession-errors`, it may have a relevant message near the end. Other than that, I don't expect that you'll be able to find useful traces of what happens. Next time, check what you're killing before you kill it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the end, I just unplugged the disk, but I might try this (if I wasn't so afraid of mounting the disk).

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't make any sense. The process list must be the one **after** a umount (including **all** processes belonging to your user account). Then `/media/Panp9` does not refer to the external disk any more but to your root volume. What is the output of `ls -l /media/Panp9` in such a situation? Check `mountpoint /media/Panp9`, too.

You should use `fuser -m /dev/whatever` instead of `fuser -m /media/Panp9`; then such misunderstandings are not possible.